# Error after publishing : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

My project works fine when it runs on my localhost but after publishing to hosting service, it gives error on every place where I used DateTime.ParseExact

```
string date = "04-03-2019";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I also tried `DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd-MM-yyyy", null);`

Comment: The `InvariantCulture` should  solve this. Which leaves the input, `string date = "04-03-2019";` is not what happens on the server.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check the culture if it's set to UK Format such as  dd/mm/yyyy (UK format), because there is another format like mm/dd/yyyy (US American), since your using localhost check the time format on ur pc

Comment: yup you are right.. I just checked current culture for both cases and they are different. so what can I do now?

Comment: since your working on localhost check the date format on your pc to be same as the date you want to parse use this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12547_01/books/Sales_AppsConfigV1.2/Sales_AppsConfig_SalesProspector11.html

Comment: yup it is same as the date I want to parse. hosting service has en-US culture and my localhost has en-IN, is there any way I just fix the culture value to en-IN for hosting service

Comment: your hosting service is IIS on your pc ?

Comment: Im not familiar with samterasp but, you can check this https://www.smarterasp.net/support/kb/a1461/how-to-set-culture-in-web_config-to-change-datetime-format.aspx, if you found my answer helpful don't forget to mark it as answer

Comment: Great, glad to help !

Answer (score 0):

I think using appropriate culture for your date format resolve this.

If your input date format is "dd-MM-yyyy", try the following code.......

```
string strDate = "04-03-2019";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(strDate,
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-IN").DateTimeFormat);
```

Here "hi-IN" Culture will identify your date string in "dd-MM-yyyy" format.